# How to navigate to another page with map annotations in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

i am trying to naviagate to another page which is my details page for map markers that i have in my map controller view. so for instance if a user clicks on any marker it would take him to that markers details specifically

i created a subclass and initialized the data i need for each marker to be unique.

but now i am facing a problem with how to navigate to the next page since this annotation is not a variable.

here is my code:

my subclass:

```
class MyAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation{
    var shopPID: String!

    init(shopPID: String) {
         self.shopPID = shopPID
    }
    
}
```

adding the markers:

```
  db.collection("Shops").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            
                    let lat = document["latitude"] as? String
                    let long = document["longitude"] as? String
                    let myFloat = (lat! as NSString).doubleValue
                    let myFloat2 = (long! as NSString).doubleValue
                    let annotation = MyAnnotation(shopPID: document["shopPID"] as! String)
                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myFloat, longitude: myFloat2)
                    annotation.title = document["name"] as? String
                    annotation.subtitle = "Click to view shop details"
                    annotation.shopPID = document["shopPID"] as? String
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

performing the click events and the segue:

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
       print(#function)
       
       if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "mapToDetails", sender: nil)
       }
   }
```

here is where i have a problem: i need to give a value to the newProjectVC that is stored in the annotations.
how would i do that?

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
 

   if (segue.identifier == "mapToDetails") {
    
        let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let newProjectVC = navigationController.topViewController as! detailsSectionViewController
        newProjectVC.getKey = //variable with each shopPID for each pin should be here
    }
    }
```

any help? thank you
[image]

This circle has my identifier "mapsToDetails"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this MKMapViewDelegate method to set a custom action when your annotation is tapped.

First subclass MKAnnotation:

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var shopPID: String
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?

    init(shopPID: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
         self.shopPID = shopPID
         self.coordinate = coordinate
         self.title = title
         self.subtitle = subtitle
    }   
}
```

Then, on your MKMapViewDelegate use:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    
    guard let annotation = view.annotation as? MyAnnotation else { return }
    
    let uiStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    guard let vc = myStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController else { return }
    vc.shopPID = annotation.shopPID
    present(vc, animated: true)
    
}
```

This way you can identify the tapped annotation and pass its values to your desired VC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what should i do in my for loop? how do i add the annotations with my shopPID?

Comment: this way is not working and a bit incomplete. i cant set title with my annotations or subtitle.

Comment: I edited my answer with annotation title, subtitle and coordinates :)

Comment: For adding the annotations you can do it the same way, using the initializer in your MKAnnotation subclass and adding the created annotation to map mapView.addAnnotation(annotation). On the other hand if you want a custom view for your custom annotations you should subclass MKAnnotationView. Hope this helps!

Comment: because your subclass extends only mkAnotations not mkpointannotations

Comment: also how you didnt include the segue and transformation to another page

Comment: For your desired functionality you are better using the MKAnnotation subclass I showed you. So please replace your MKPoint with this MKAnnotation subclass and try it out. As for the segue there are many ways to show a ViewController, this one is better for this case as you are free to pass any data to your presenting ViewController. Don't forget you have to place the ViewController identifier on your storyboard.

Comment: i am getting an error on this line  `vc.shopPID = annotation.shopPID that reads "value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'shopPID'"`

Comment: Sorry you should ad as MyViewController when you define your destination VC. I edited my answer. Please let my know :)

Comment: okay its working fine now, but i have a navigationController not a view controller with my ID what should i do in this case? i think your method will work fine if this is fixed

Comment: Instead of the let vc line then you could use guard let nc = myStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyNavigationControllerId") as? UINavigationController else {.return } and then access its first VC as your "DetailsSectionViewController" to pass it the parameters before presenting it. Another way is to embed the vc in a NavigationController like this let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc). If this answers your question I would really appreciate if you could mark my answer as selected :)

Comment: thank you for your effort but your method is not working for me. i keep getting errors that i dont have a view controller with identifier mapToDetails.

Comment: No worries, here is an example where I get the first VC in my NavigationController and give it a param before presenting my NC.
guard let nc = myStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyNavigationControllerId") as? UINavigationController else { return }
        if let myVC = nc.viewControllers.first as? MyViewController {
            myVC.shopPID = annotation.shopPID
            self.present(nc, animated: true)
        }

Comment: your method seems to be perfect but it keeps giving me that error which is very unfortunate.

Comment: The error I see is that either your DetailsSectionViewController has no member 'shopPID' so you would need to define your variable in it, Or that you are not casting the UIViewController as your DetailsSectionViewController, which you should be careful you added the "as? DetailsSectionViewController" when you define your vc on your code.

Comment: no its not that, check my edited question ill add an image

Comment: Ok I see, the identifier you should use when instantiating a VC or NC from your Storyboard always must be the Storyboard ID under the Identity Inspector in your Storyboard. Please set that identifier to match the used one in .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier") and remove the segue as you don't longer need it. If you have more questions about navigations and segues please feel free to ask a new question and mark this one as answered, as Stack Overflow advices against too long comment sections and the question about navigating from annotations has been resolved. Greetings!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort, it works perfectly now!!! amazing answer, detailed and you followed all my problems thank you sir