# Navigating to another View from Annotation in MKMapView

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I have a list of items I am bringing over from a database to an MKMapView View. I query the Apple servers to convert a city and state to a latitude and longitude. All of this works.

What I'm trying to do is, when an annotation is clicked on, I need to navigate the user to an view called ItemView(item: clickedOnItem), sending in the item.

So as I understand, I need to add something in mapView in the Controller / delegate, not sure what I'm supposed to add in order to navigate to ItemView(item: item)

Here is my MKAnnotation:

```
class ToDoLocationAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation, Identifiable {
    let name: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let toDoItem: ToDoItem
    
    init(toDoItem: ToDoItem,
         name: String?,
         coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.name = name
        self.toDoItem = toDoItem
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

And my view...

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var items: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>
    
    init(items: FetchedResults<ToDoItem>) {
        self.items = items
    }
    
    func getCoordinateFrom(location: String, completion: @escaping(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(location) {
            completion($0?.first?.location?.coordinate, $1)
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 39.299236, longitude: -76.609383)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        items.forEach({ item in
            if item.completed == false {
                getCoordinateFrom(location: item.location!) { coordinate, error in
                    guard let coordinate = coordinate, error == nil else { return }
                    view.addAnnotation(ToDoLocationAnnotation(toDoItem: item, name: item.location!, coordinate: coordinate))
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

...and of course my delegate:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var parent: MapView

    init(_ parent: MapView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        return view
    }
}
```

If I use the standard Map() function, I could do this:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: locationList.locations ) { item in
    MapAnnotation(coordinate: item.coordinate) {
        NavigationLink(destination: ToDoItemView(item: item.toDoItem)) {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I saw this related SO post: [How to navigate to another page with map annotations in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814911/how-to-navigate-to-another-page-with-map-annotations-in-swift), it didn't seem to do what I was looking for?

Comment: What is your question? What doesn’t work?

Comment: I'll update the question to be more intuitive. I also realized I'm missing my delegate. I'm trying to figure out why / how to navigate to another view if someone clicks on an annotation. For instance, I click on a specific item, navigate to the ItemView(item: item)

Comment: Search for "programatic navigation SwiftUI" to see some options.